Azure Web App: User in container has group missing
I have a container that I am trying to run in Azure WebApps. Locally the container works fine and the container user nginx has the following id output
uid=1000(nginx) gid=1000(nginx) groups=1000(nginx),0(root)

When running in the Azure WebApp, the user has the following groups and thus the container fails to start up:
uid=1000(nginx) gid=1000(nginx) groups=1000(nginx)

The user is added to the root group in the base image but the assignment is missing in Azure WebApps.
